# create an image in the canvas using a button event tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I need to add an event to my buttons in a Tkinter gui that will create an image in the canvas. How do I do it?

Thanks All

It works but I need to get a dynamic number images of the same image file, but everytime I create a new image the old image gets garbage collected. I cant think of what to do. I want to have multiple instances of the same image on my canvas. Please, would be glad for some suggestions

my code

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


def callback():
        if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
            root.destroy()

class AppUI(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):

            Frame.__init__(self, master, background="white", relief=FLAT, bd=2, height=768, width=1024)

            self.menubar = Menu(self)

            menu = Menu(self.menubar)
            self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=menu)
            menu.add_command(label="New")
            menu.add_command(label="Open")
            menu.add_command(label="Save As")
            menu.add_command(label="Save Copy of")
            menu.add_separator()
            menu.add_command(label="exit")

            menu = Menu(self.menubar)
            self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=menu)
            menu.add_command(label="Cut")
            menu.add_command(label="Copy")
            menu.add_command(label="Paste")

            menu = Menu(self.menubar)
            self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Debug", menu=menu)
            menu.add_command(label="Open Debugger")
            menu.add_command(label="Auto-debug")
            menu.add_command(label="Revert")

            menu = Menu(self.menubar)
            self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Run", menu=menu)
            menu.add_command(label="Stimulation")
            menu.add_command(label="Check")
            menu.add_command(label="Scan Module")

            menu = Menu(self.menubar)
            self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=menu)
            menu.add_command(label="Help files")
            menu.add_command(label="FTA site")
            menu.add_separator()
            menu.add_command(label="Credits")

            self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)      

            f0 = Frame(root, background="white")

            b1 = Button(f0, bd=2, padx=15, pady=15, justify = LEFT)
            photo1 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p1.gif")
            b1.config(image = photo1,width="50",height="50", command=self.create_image1)
            b1.image = photo1
            b1.pack(side=LEFT)

            b2 = Button(f0, bd=2, padx=15, pady=15, justify = LEFT)
            photo2 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p4.gif")
            b2.config(image=photo2, width="50",height="50", command = self.create_image2)
            b2.image = photo2
            b2.pack(side=LEFT)

            b3 = Button(f0,padx=15, bd=2, pady=15, justify = LEFT)
            photo3 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p8.gif")
            b3.config(image=photo3, width="50",height="50", command = self.create_image3)
            b3.image = photo3
            b3.pack(side=LEFT)

            b4 = Button(f0,padx=15, bd=2, pady=15, justify = LEFT)
            photo4 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p7.gif")
            b4.config(image=photo4, width="50",height="50", command = self.create_image4)
            b4.image = photo4
            b4.pack(side=LEFT)

            b5 = Button(f0,padx=15, bd=2, pady=15, justify = LEFT)
            photo5 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p5.gif")
            b5.config(image=photo5, width="50",height="50", command=self.create_image5)
            b5.image = photo5
            b5.pack(side=LEFT)

            f0.pack(anchor=NW, side=TOP)

            self.canvas = Canvas(self, height=750, width=1500, bg="white")
            self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT)

    def create_image1(self):
            photos1 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p1.gif")
            self.photos1=photos1
            self.img1=self.canvas.create_image(60, 60, image=photos1)
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_image1)

    def create_image2(self):
            photos2 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p4.gif")
            self.photos2=photos2
            self.img2=self.canvas.create_image(60, 60, image=photos2)
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_image2)

    def create_image3(self):
            photos3 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p8.gif")
            self.photos3=photos3
            self.img3=self.canvas.create_image(60, 60, image=photos3)
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_image3)

    def create_image4(self):
            photos4 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p7.gif")
            self.photos4=photos4
            self.img4=self.canvas.create_image(60, 60, image=photos4)
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_image4)

    def create_image5(self):
            photos5 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p5.gif")
            self.photos5=photos5
            self.img5=self.canvas.create_image(60, 60, image=photos5)        
            self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_image5)

    def move_image1(self, event):
            self.canvas.delete(self.img1)
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            self.img1 = self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photos1, anchor='nw')
            self.canvas.update()
    def move_image2(self, event):
            self.canvas.delete(self.img2)
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            self.img2 = self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photos2, anchor='nw')
            self.canvas.update()
    def move_image3(self, event):
            self.canvas.delete(self.img3)
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            self.img3 = self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photos3, anchor='nw')
            self.canvas.update()
    def move_image4(self, event):
            self.canvas.delete(self.img4)
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            self.img4 = self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photos4, anchor='nw')
            self.canvas.update()
    def move_image5(self, event):
            self.canvas.delete(self.img5)
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            self.img5 = self.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photos5, anchor='nw')
            self.canvas.update()        


root = Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)

app = AppUI(root)
app.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, only the last drawn image can be dragged and dropped All previous images cannot be interacted with. And, as I said, I cant seem to create multiple clone images. I know that I should anchor all the images so that they don't get garbage collected but I cant seem to find out a way to do that. I tried return the image instance of the function create_image to an array. but it didn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are asking someone to write code for you. What have you tried? What has failed? Show some effort.

Comment: Umm!! I just need to get some Idea. I dont know about binding individual widgets in a canvas. A will add my code

Comment: And so very sorry for crappy coding, I am just starting python.

Comment: It's all right, as long as you try :). If you show that you've tried, you will get help more easily and will be able to accomplish more in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What problem are you specifically having? There's nothing tricky about it:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
    b = tk.Button(..., command=self.create_image)
    ...
def create_image(self):
    self.canvas.create_image(...)
```

The important thing to remember is that the images will get garbage-collected unless you keep a reference to them. Since you are creating multiple images, an easy way to do this is to create a list to which you can append references to the images:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.images = []
    ...
    photo1 = PhotoImage(file="Images/p1.gif")
    self.images.append(photo1)
    ...
```

There are some other problems with your code. For one, you don't need to delete and then recreate the images when they are moved. The canvas has a `move` method specifically for moving existing items. Also, the calls to `self.canvas.update()` are completely useless.

Finally, your code will be considerably easier to maintain if you only have a single "move" method, rather than one for each image. That's off topic for this specific question, but you might want to search for `lambda` and `functools.partial` as solutions for being able to pass arguments via bindings.